# Ubuntu Boots to terminal after update + dist-upgrade Instead of GUI ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates

I just upgraded 3 of my Ubuntu machines with update + dist-upgrade. After updates I rebooted all my machines, and now they only boot to the Terminal instead of the GUI..

When I log into the terminal there is no interfaces can't ping nothing. I've tried other commands like "gnome-session" etc and nothing works all 3 computers are like this. Anyone know how to get the GUI back. I have lot's of important work on these HDDs. Never had this before.

Comment: I have the same problem. Today suddenly apt wanted to remove 125 packages including some essential ones, like `ubuntu-desktop`. I did not proceed with upgrade, the system works fine, but don't know what to do next.

Comment: There is report of similar problem on ubuntuforums here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479362

Comment: This bug is reported on Launchpad and assigned critical: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1990586

Comment: Root cause seems to be fixed. To repair damage, you are advised to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @IlyaPopov you seem to have 90% of an answer to this question already. Consider getting credit for your hard work and research by writing an answer than can be upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

How I recovered from this:
boot to recovery mode from grub.

Enable network.

Enable file access.

Go to shell & press enter.

command : apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop